# Showing Event from API to Flutter Carousel Calender

Tags: api, flutter, dart, calendar, carousel

I want to show a Carousel Calendar and mark present ,absent and leave of a student by using Rest Api. I need to show these events by different color. The event already exists from API.

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. You need to add some code to describe what have you done so far & what are you stuck with? Are you stuck with creating the carousel calendar or showing the events in calendar or both? Have you tried using calendar packages that are avaialble? I know a few that can easily help you in building the same.

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi Im already done the carousel calender .Then now I need to show the absent,present and leave dates in calender by the particular response of the rest api.i just want to show the particular dates realted to these events to the calender.That's all

Comment: Which library did you use for the calendar carousel?

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi   flutter_calendar_carousel: ^1.4.12

Comment: You can use the `customDayBuilder` property. What kind of data do you get from the API?

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi    list of data,    {
  "details": [
    {
      "date": "2020-11-01T10:42:13.082Z",
      "status": "string",
      "remarks": "string"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your timestamp data from the API into a `DateTime` object.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(timestamp);
```

And then use the `customDayBuilder` property to define the appropriate widget with the color that you want.

```
customDayBuilder: (   /// you can provide your own build function to make custom day containers
        bool isSelectable,
        int index,
        bool isSelectedDay,
        bool isToday,
        bool isPrevMonthDay,
        TextStyle textStyle,
        bool isNextMonthDay,
        bool isThisMonthDay,
        DateTime day,
      ) {
          /// If you return null, [CalendarCarousel] will build container for current [day] with default function.
          /// This way you can build custom containers for specific days only, leaving rest as default.


          if (day.difference(dateTime).inDays == 0) {
            // Do additional checks for status, remarks or for checking
            // whether the day should be marked as absent, present or something else
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red // Change this color according to your case.
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
            );
          } else {
            return null; // returning null will build container for current [day] with default function.
          }
      },
```